# softdeleteable filter not working in Symfony with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, soft-delete

We are creating an API-REST with Symfony 3.4 and using mongodb as db

All the mapping and cofiguration has been done, and it works.

buuuuuuuttt...
The softdeleteable filter is not working, I mean:

- If I "delete" one document, the deletedAt works fine.
- Then, if I try to get all the documents of this collection, or even just THAT document, I CAN DO IT !!! even if it's deleted.
- And if I delete again that same document, it is fully deleted from the database.

This is my config.yml :

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    mongodb:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            softdeleteable: true
            translatable: true
            loggable: true
            uploadable: true
    translation_fallback: true
    uploadable: 
        default_file_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/files/"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_database: "%mongodb_default_db%"
    document_managers:
        default:
            retry_connect: 5
            retry_query: 5
            auto_mapping: true
            filters:
                softdeleteable:
                    class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\ODM\SoftDeleteableFilter
                    enabled: true
            mappings:
                #translatable
                gedmo_translatable:
                    type: annotation
                    alias: GedmoTranslatable
                    prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Document
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Document"
                    is_bundle: false
                #loggable
                gedmo_loggable:
                    type: annotation
                    alias: GedmoLoggable
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Document
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Document"
                    is_bundle: false        
    proxy_namespace:      MongoDBODMProxies
    proxy_dir:            "%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Proxies"
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
```

An example of the mapping:

```
Example\ExampleBundle\Model\Example:
    collection: example
    gedmo:
        loggable: true
        translation:
            locale: locale
        soft_deleteable:
            field_name: deletedAt
            time_aware: false
    fields:
        id:
            type: object_id
            id: true
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            gedmo:
                - translatable
                - versioned
        description:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            gedmo:
                - translatable
                - versioned
        createdAt:
            name: created_at
            type: date
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: create
        updatedAt:
            name: updated_at
            type: date
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: update
        deletedAt:
            name: deleted_at
            type: date
            nullable: true
```

And my model:

```
class Example
{
    private $id;
    ...
    private $createdAt;
    private $updatedAt;
    private $deletedAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }
}
```

In the controller, for example, to get a document by its ID, I have:

```
/**
 * Get a single entity.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="Get a single Example.",
 *  output= {"class"=Example::class},
 *  statusCodes={
 *      200="Returned when successful",
 *      404="Returned when not found"
 *  },
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="id", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="Example id"}
 *  }
 * )
 *
 * @FOS\Get("/example/{id}", requirements={"id": "([a-f\d]{24})|(\d+)"})
 * @FOS\View
 *
 * @param Example $example
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getExampleAction(Example $example)
{
    return array('example' => $example);
}
```

please, what am I doing wrong?

I have already 2 days trying different things but nothing :(

Comment: Please paste the code you're using to get the documents.

Comment: How do you disable the filter to retrieve your softdeleted items? you must have something like `$em->getFilterCollection()->disable('soft-deleteable');` in your service/controller.

Comment: @malarzm i edited my question to put the code used  in my controller to get a document by its ID
Then, using the route http://{{URI}}/example/5abb5c94b3525009763e87f2 in postman, i can get the document even if in the db i can see **deleted_at: 2018-04-03 14:57:01.000**

Comment: @LBA i'm not trying to retrieve the softdeleted items, but the other ones... anyway i can get all or when i get by its ID, even if the deletedAt is setted and i don't want that... i would like only the documents that have not been deleted

Comment: What if instead of retrieving all documents in your query, you retrieve all except the ones that have the `deleted_at` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

in the documentation it's say:
"For now, it works only with the ORM"

https://github.com/stof/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

So i think it's not totally works with ODM, sorry. 
Can you complete your querys to check the deletedAt field?